# How to force input language in a textbox to be English

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

It's more of a cosmetics in the app,but let's say someone is entering his email in a textbox and he has 3 languages installed EN,CH,and Urdu. since emails are on in English, when the user clicks on the textbox his language automatically switchs to EN.

let's say the user forgets to change the language and he had the default to be CH. then when this user clicks the textbox, instead of writing in a wrong language for a while before switching to EN. he finds that the app automatically changes his language to EN

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just allowing ascii input would be a viable solution? You can add a message that only english character input is allowed or something.

An alternative is changing the language on the client system to EN when entering/leaving the box but I guess that requires too much access on the client's system.